# Angular2 Lifecycle hooks not working as thought with loading content

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a main component that renders among other things divs next to one other that has position:absolute. I have written a script that measures the content in the divs and expands all the divs to the height of the highest div so that all of them are the same height. The script runs with `ngAfterViewInit`. But in testing I always put in random content in the child component, and now I load content with a "get" api request. But the problem is that it seems to me that the api request takes too long, and by then the parent `ngAfterViewInit`have already fired, sees there is no content, makes the size of the divs extremely small, and then the content loads, but you only see the first line because the rest are cut of seeing that the main div is not stretched to the right height.

My app looks basically like this:

**Parent component**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   Works out how high the divs must be and sets the height in the css.
}
```

**Child component**

```
ngOnInit() {
   Gets the data using a get api request form the server.
}
```

I have tried changing the `ngAfterViewInit` to a `onChanges` hook which did nothing, and a few other things, but I feel that there must be some small change that I can do to make the `ngAfterViewInit` check the height of the child components only after all the content have loaded.

**UPDATE**

I logged every component to see what is happening:

```
Parent ngOnInit
child ngOnInit
child ngOnInit
child ngOnInit
child ngOnInit
child ngOnInit
child ngOnInit
child ngOnInit
Parent ngAfterViewInit
lang.js:137 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Set
Set
Set
Set
Set
Set
Set
```

**UPDATE2**

Here is my function working out the height of each div, and applying the value to the main div.

Parent component

```
largestHeight() {
    let largestHeight = this.divs.reduce((topHeight, divValue) => { 
        let currentDiv = divValue.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        return (currentDiv.height > topHeight ? currentDiv.height : topHeight); 
     }, 0);
    this._renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainContainerRef.nativeElement, 'height', largestHeight + 80 + 'px');
    this.divs.forEach((names) => {
    this._renderer.setElementStyle(names.nativeElement, 'height', largestHeight + 'px');
    console.log(largestHeight);
    }); 
   }
```

Here I use the function in the callback of the subscribe method

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      this._httpService.getPostsByBlogger()
            .subscribe(x => this.posts = x,
                error => console.log("Error: ", error),
                () => this.largestHeight());
   }
```

Child Component

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log("child ngOnChanges");
          if (changes['data']) {
              this.groupPosts = this.groupByCategory(this.data);
          }

      }

    groupByCategory(data: DB[]): GroupPosts[] {
        if (!data) return

        const categories = new Set(data.map(x => x.Leaning));
        console.dir(categories);
                const result = Array.from(categories).map(x => ({
            Leaning: x,
            posts: data.filter(post => post.Leaning === x)
        }));

        return result;
```

Simplified HTML structure

```
<div id="parent"> //this div has css position:absolute, so it does not contract or expand as data is inserted
  <div id="child"> //this div is normal, and gets the data (that is also sorted). 
  </div> // The parent div gets it's size form the child div, but now the parent div gets the size before the child div is rendered.
</div>
```

Comment: You need to ensure the code is called once by the event that happens last - either the response from the `get` api or `ngAfterViewInit`. You can use a flag to indicate that `ngAfterViewInit` or `get` response have happened and then execute the code or not.

Comment: Hi, So would the last event be `ngAfterViewInit` based on my edit above. Could you maybe give a code snippet (just the shell) to show what the flag would look like...

Comment: There is no lifycycle hook where you can be sure a server request has already returned. A request to a server takes an eternity compared to code executed inside the browser only. You would be better off assumeing that `ngAfterViewInit()` has been called when the server request returned and therefore put the code into the `subscribe(...)` callback.

Comment: What's the problem (actual vs expected behavior) with your current code?

Comment: Hi Gunter, I had another crack at it this morning and added my `largestHeight` function to the subscription callback, but there was no change. (Added the actual code to my question under "UPDATE2"). As you can see on the log that I posted (under "UPDATE") there are all these "SET" items happening after everything else was done.

Comment: I can't see from your code what causes `Set` to be printed and therefore can't make sense of that log.

Comment: The problem is that the divs that take my data (that I get from API request) are position:absolute (can not do it another way because of placement), so as my data comes in, it overruns the size of the div due to the fact that the div is not pushed larger by the extra data(a negative about position:absolute). So I created a normal div, inside the absolute div that does stretch with the data, and then I get the height of the normal div, and give this height to the parent (absolute) div. But now the child div only gets the data once the parent div is already resized...

Comment: Hi Gunter, I have made a new small program showing my problem clearly, and posted a new question with it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291062/angular2-lifecycle-hook-working-on-local-data-but-not-api-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given in a follow-up question at this link: [Angular2 lifecycle hook working on local data, but not api data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291062/angular2-lifecycle-hook-working-on-local-data-but-not-api-data)

But in short the `ngAfterViewInit` hook needed to be changed to calling the `largestHeight' after all elements were rendered.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
...
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

ngOnInit() { 
   this.getPosts()
     .subscribe(x => { 
        this.apidata = x;
        this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => {
          this.largestHeight(); 
        });
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change to this lifecycle event `ngAfterViewChecked` as this is triggered also if the view of a child changes.

When the child will be updated the parent `ngAfterViewChecked` will trigger and call again your js.

Comment: Hi, I have tried for 2 hours now to get the `ngAfterViewChecked ` to work, but I think if you look at the edit I did on my code showing the life cycle hooks, you can see why it did not work. The data gets set after the life cycle hooks have fired....